# How make a custom QPushButton in PyQt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to add a big button which will start some process. I know that I can make QPushButton large enough, however, I wish it be something like that 
 [image]

 What can you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flat QPushButton with transparent icon.